# Wrap label text

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to text of the labels on a form column?  We want to change the label for Customer Reference just on SO301000 which I can do with SetDisplayName, but even the standard label does not fit the current column width. I would like to make the label a little longer and it would look better wrapped.

Comment: Do you want to simply change the size of the label on Customer Reference field or the goal is to place the label on top of the input control? Both options are feasible, I just wanted to clarify which one you pursue.

Comment: Sorry, my initial question had a typo. I was wondering a long label can be wrapped to two rows on a form screen.  I know that will waste some vertical space, but it might be useful in some cases.  I have since found where to customize the label width via the customization project, but I could not find a wrap property.  I'm not sure what you mean by putting the label on top of the input control.  If it is too long and the input control is full, would it hide the data?

Answer (score 0):

One thought to wrap the text is to insert a line break HTML tag in the display name.  The only issue with this I found is I had to add a hidden label field below the field I wanted to wrap because it caused a layout issue with the field below it.

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<Location.taxRegistrationID>(cache, "Tax <br/> Registration");
```